# twain scanner Check connected devices

Tags: vb.net

I used the following code to read the scanner file and review it in the image box with twain scanner.
It works well if the scanner is connected to the computer.
If the scanner is not connected, the code stops the  form and does not close.

I want a way to check the scanner connection or cancel if the scanner is not connected to the device (pc)

```
  Try
             Dim s As Collection
    
             s = SCANNER.ScanImages()
    
             For Each k In s
    
                 PictureBox1.Load(k)
    
             Next
         Catch ex As Exception
             MsgBox(ex.Message)
         End Try
```

Comment: Wat library are you using ?

Comment: HI Anonymous  simple library program:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_WQdhexcq_-yOHdMGEPiIMvf2cjthtmF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: But that doesn't tell us what library you are using. You must have some kind of DLL to use it ? You are obviously using a third-party so there should be some documentation describing usage. Do you have an online link ?

Comment: It is a free class with Free Code

Comment: As far as I can see, there doesn't look to be anything in that free class that indicates connection status.  Options I see are 1) go back to the author of that class, as for methods/properties to check connection.  or implement your own connection check, doing something like checking the port status maybe